# Regex pattern to find multiple timestamp formats avoid single numbers alone

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to create a regex patter that will find multiple time formats such as:

I expect these outputs to match:

```
11:00PM - 11:00pm
11:00 PM - 11:00pm
11.PM
11.pm
21:00AM - 21am
21:00
11:00
```

**I want the regex to match the patterns above**, and it currently does however, this also find pm, PM, am, AM and double digit numbers as well, how can I avoid this? Meaning single numbers an PM, AM alone will not be accepted?

So for example:

```
PM
AM
11
21
1
```

Will also be accepted by my regex.

**EDIT**
My intention is to ***avoid*** mention cases such as:

```
PM
AM
11
21
1
```

**EDIT 2**

I have fixed the issue with match `pm, am, PM, AM` however, it is still matching numerical numbers that are 1 or 2 digits:

`(\d{1,2})([.:](\d{1,2}))?[ .]?(am|pm|PM|AM)?`

Here is a link to my current pattern:

[Regex Pattern](https://regexr.com/5jmjh)

Comment: What kind of output you are looking for? Which values should the pattern match?

Comment: I added more clarification, the regex does match both, however, I do not want it to match the second pard meaning PM, AM, and double digit numbers or single digit numbers alone.

Comment: Do you really expect things like `11.PM`?  How is this a valid time at all?

Comment: I am filtering out times from a webpage, and some do have that format, so as precaution I have added that, my main issue however, is that it is matching single and double digit numbers as well as PM and am alone. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like the output to look like?

Comment: I have added which outputs  I expect to match @DanielFreeman

Comment: Sorry, I reread your question and I still don't understand what you're after. Can you explicitly state the input and desired output?

Comment: @DanielFreeman The OP wants to just _assert_ whether the inputs match the expected patterns.  That's all `:-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex pattern seems to be catching everything you want, while excluding what you don't want:

```
^\d+(?:(?:\.|:\d+)[ ]*(?:am|AM|pm|PM)?|(?:am|AM|pm|PM))(?:[ ]*-[ ]*\d+(?:(?:\.|:\d+)[ ]*(?:am|AM|pm|PM)?|(?:am|AM|pm|PM)))*$
```

### Demo

Here is an R script using `grepl` which verifies that the pattern works in R:

```r
x <- c("11:00PM - 11:00pm", "11:00 PM - 11:00pm", "11.PM", "11.pm", "21:00AM - 21am",
       "21:00", "11:00", "PM", "AM", "11", "21", "1")
grepl("^\\d+(?:(?:\\.|:\\d+)[ ]*(?:am|AM|pm|PM)?|(?:am|AM|pm|PM))(?:[ ]*-[ ]*\\d+(?:(?:\\.|:\\d+)[ ]*(?:am|AM|pm|PM)?|(?:am|AM|pm|PM)))*$", x)

[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Yes exactly this avoid matching numerical numbers, which was my main issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based one your question it sounds like you want the input to contain a digit and some type of format (colon, am/pm, etc.). This should accomplish that:

```
pass <- c("11:00PM - 11:00pm", "11:00 PM - 11:00pm", "11.PM", "11.pm", 
          "21:00AM - 21am", "21:00", "11:00")
fail <- c("PM", "AM", "11", "21", "1")

stringr::str_detect(pass, ":|am|pm|AM|PM") & stringr::str_detect(pass, "\\d") # all TRUE
stringr::str_detect(fail, ":|am|pm|AM|PM") & stringr::str_detect(fail, "\\d") # all FALSE
```

Comment: The problem with your TRUE pattern is that it would also match things like `:03` or `3:`,which maybe the OP does not want to accept.